# What is a good explanation of how a card shuffling program works?

Tags: c, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the below program works. The program is designed to shuffle a deck of cards in a random order.

Could someone explain some of the details of the functions and how exactly the code works? I understand the use of the two dimensional array but some of the shuffle function confuses me along with the last print statement:

`printf( "%5s of %-8s%c", wFace[ column ], wSuit[ row ],card % 2 == 0 ? '\n':'\t' );`

Here is the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #define SUITS 4
   #define FACES 13
   #define CARDS 52
   // prototypes

 void shuffle( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ] ); // shuffling modifies wDeck
 void deal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[],
 const char *wSuit[] ); // dealing doesn't modify the arrays

int main( void )
{

const char *suit[ SUITS ] =
 { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
 // initialize face array

 const char *face[ FACES ] =
 { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
 "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
 "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

 unsigned int deck[ SUITS ][ FACES ] = { 0 };

 srand( time( NULL ) ); // seed random-number generator


 shuffle( deck ); // shuffle the deck
 deal( deck, face, suit ); // deal the deck
 }


 /*SHUFFLE FUNCTION*/
 void shuffle( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ] ){

 size_t row;
 size_t column;
 size_t card;

 for ( card = 1; card <= CARDS; ++card ) {
  do {
  row = rand() % SUITS;
  column = rand() % FACES;
  } while( wDeck[ row ][ column ] != 0 );

  wDeck[ row ][ column ] = card;}}

  void deal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[], 
  const char    *wSuit[] ){

 size_t card;
 size_t row;
 size_t column;

  for ( card = 1; card <= CARDS; ++card ) {

   for ( row = 0; row < SUITS; ++row ) {

     for ( column = 0; column < FACES; ++column ) {

     if ( wDeck[ row ][ column ] == card ) {

    printf( "%5s of %-8s%c", wFace[ column ], wSuit[ row ],
     card % 2 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t' ); // 2-column format
       }}}}}
```

Comment: The last `printf` statement creates two columns using modulo - if card is odd, it outputs a tab (`\t`), and if card is even it outputs a newline (`\n`). You haven't asked any specific questions or even explained what part of the shuffle functions you don't understand; nothing in this code is complicated. If you have a question about specific code, ask a specific question. We're not going to go through line by line to explain it. A C tutorial teaches the language basics, and there's not a lot more than that here.

Comment: It is bad code, throw it away.  Google "fisher yates shuffle" to find good code.

Comment: `for ( card = 1; card <= CARDS; ++card ) {` suspect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the shuffle function is

```
 for ( card = 1; card <= CARDS; ++card ) {
  do {
  row = rand() % SUITS;
  column = rand() % FACES;
  } while( wDeck[ row ][ column ] != 0 );
  wDeck[ row ][ column ] = card;}
```

It keeps guessing a face and a suit until it finds a combination which is not in the deck yet, then it assigns it to the next card in the deck.

The confusing `printf` function just prints all cards in two columns, like Ken explained.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the name of the cards into the arrays like such:


const char *suit[ SUITS ] =
 { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
 // initialize face array

 const char *face[ FACES ] =
 { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
 "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
 "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };



How to enter them through a scanf piece of code?